# How to render radar-chart with live data and dynamic array entries?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Chart Library: danielgindi/Charts

chartView is RadarChartView Object

```
chartView.clear()
chartView.clearValues()
let set1 = RadarChartDataSet(entries: arrRadarProduct, label: "XXX")
let data = RadarChartData(dataSets: [set1])
data.notifyDataChanged()
chartView.data = data
chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

refresh X entries values click on refresh button sometimes it X entries could be between 6 to 12 value at that time accessibilityXLabels value not change in library because it is lazy variable.

**expect to happen**

accessibilityXLabels value change on refresh

**happened**

```
let accessibilityAxisLabelValueTuples = zip(accessibilityXLabels, accessibilityEntryValues).map { ($0, $1.0, $1.1) }.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

library crash due to accessibilityEntryValues has new value but accessibilityXLabels old values.

How to update XValues in RadarChart?

Comment: Hard to understand your flow here. Can you please share a) The method that initialized your chart and b) The method that updates your chart ?

Comment: Can you further elaborate the issue?